# Ошибка при построении модуля

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babel, jsx

Я получаю такую ошибку, в чем может быть проблема? state = {} считает не верным. Почему так может быть?
[image: Ошибка. state = {} считает не верным, в связи с чем не могу построить.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use functions only

```
export default class Auth extends Component {

   get state(){
      return {
         formControls:{...}
      };
   }
}
```

OR in constructor :

```
export default class Auth extends Component {

    constructor(){
       super();

       this.state = {
           formControls:{...}
       };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ругается на синтаксис, так как стэйт ни как не обьявлено. В реакте стэйт должно быть свойством у компонента. Что из себя представляет "state" можно посмотреть тут:  https://metanit.com/web/react/2.4.php

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]